# change year for a date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date

I have a form that gets the birthday of a user.

I want to take the birthday and store it in another attribute but take the current year.

I do this in a call back

Model board

before_save :set_delivery_date

```
def set_delivery_date

self.delivery_date = self.birthday
self.delivery_date.change(:year => Time.now.year)
end
```

The birthday is 1920-07-27

This does not seem to change the date.

Anyone know how to do this?

**Update**

The following works I can see the new date in the database:

```
 self.deliver_on = self.birthday.change(:year => Time.now.year)
```

However when I try to do rspec tests or I try it in the console it produces the following error:

```
ArgumentError: invalid date
```

anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The change method returns a new date instance with one or more elements changed.

Try this:

```
def set_delivery_date
   self.delivery_date = self.birthday
   self.delivery_date = self.delivery_date.change(:year => Time.now.year)
end
```

Comment: Watch our for leap years, e.g. `date = Date.parse('29/02/2016'); date.change(year: date.year + 1) # => ArgumentError: invalid date`.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord's [Dirty Object](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/31/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-dirty-objects) feature does not know about your changes. There are two ways to fix this:

```
def set_delivery_date
  self.delivery_date = self.birthday
  self.delivery_date = self.delivery_date.change(:year => Time.now.year)

  # Shorter
  self.delivery_date = self.birthday.change(:year => Time.now.year)
end
```

or tell ActiveRecord about your changes:

```
def set_delivery_date
  self.delivery_date = self.birthday
  self.delivery_date_will_change!
  self.delivery_date.change(:year => Time.now.year)
end
```

Comment: I tried both solutions and now I am getting invalid date. Very strange as I am only changing the year. Any ideas?

Comment: self.birthday.change(:year => Time.now.year produces an invalid_date exception

Comment: Can you post your tests, or maybe validate `birthday` before actually start working with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. So I would check reasons why your object is not saved:

- the object is not valid? E.g. `object.valid?` returns false. Validation checks happen before the save.
- you are not saving?